# public function not executing

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a user Class which saves users to my MySQL dbase. This works nicely, but I am trying to log new users and changes made to existing users.
This logging function is not executing, the query, I checked, does not return any errors.

user Class:

```
class User
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($db_con)
    {
        $this->db = $db_con;
    }

    public function log_change_user($id, $action)
    {
        $usr_name = get_name($this->db, $id, 'full');
        $cur_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        if($action == 'new')
        {
            $log_act = 0;
        }
        else if($action == 'edit')
        {
            $log_act = 1;
        }
        else if($action == 'delete')
        {
            $log_act = 2;
        }
        try {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO mainlog (user, action, type, subject_id, subj_name, cdate) VALUES (:user_id, :action, 0, :id, :subj_name, now())");
            $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $cur_user);
            $stmt->bindParam(":action", $log_act);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(":subj_name", $usr_name);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function register($user_id, $fname, $lname, $prefix, $email, $pass, $role, $phone, $dob)
    {
        try
        {
            if($pass !== null)
            {
                $new_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(id, firstname, lastname, prefix, email, password, role, phone, dob, cdate) VALUES(:id, :fname, :lname, :prefix, :email, :pass, :role, :phone, :dob, now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=:fname, lastname=:lname, prefix=:prefix, email=:email, password=:pass, role=:role, phone=:phone, dob=:dob, edate=now()");

                $stmt->bindparam(":pass", $new_password);
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(id, firstname, lastname, prefix, email, role, phone, dob, cdate) VALUES(:id, :fname, :lname, :prefix, :email, :role, :phone, :dob, now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=:fname, lastname=:lname, prefix=:prefix, email=:email, role=:role, phone=:phone, dob=:dob, edate=now()");

            }

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $user_id);
            $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lname", $lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":prefix", $prefix);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);

            $stmt->bindparam(":role", $role);
            $stmt->bindparam(":phone", $phone);
            $stmt->bindparam(":dob", $dob);

            $stmt->execute();

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }    
    }

    public function login($email, $pass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, password, role FROM users WHERE email=:email LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if(password_verify($pass, $row['password']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['role'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;    
        }
    }

    public function redirect($view)
    {
        $_GET['view'] = $view;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_role']);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The users.php used by my Ajax call:

```
require_once('../../../../config/config.php');

if(isset($_POST['add_user']))
{
    if($_POST['add_user'] == true)
    {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(isset($_POST['pass']))
        {
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        }
        else
        {
            $pass = '';
        }
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dob']));

        $add_user = new User($db_con);

        if($add_user->register(null, $fname, $lname, $prefix, $email, $pass, $role, $phone, $dob))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    else if($_POST['add_user'] == false)
    {
        $user_id = $_POST['uid'];
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['dob']));

        $edit_user = new User($db_con);

        if($edit_user->register($user_id, $fname, $lname, $prefix, $email, $pass, $role, $phone, $dob))
        {
            $edit_user->log_change_user($user_id, 'edit');
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_user']))
{
    $id = $_POST['delete_user'];
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:id");
    //add_log_entry($db_con, $_SESSION['user_id'], 2, 0, $id);
    if($stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id)))
    {
        echo true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['get_user_data']))
{
    $id = $_POST['get_user_data'];
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo json_encode($record);

}

if(isset($_POST['user_full_name']))
{
    $id = $_POST['user_full_name'];
    echo get_name($db_con, $id, 'full');
}
```

Comment: You're checking `$_POST[...] == false` but that will "never" be the case because POST data are always strings (not never, but it's just a wrong assumption to make).

Comment: I didn't know that, but the data sent by the ajax call sets the `$_POST['add_user']` to either true or false.

Comment: Its probably going to be either `$_POST['add_user'] == 'true'` or `$_POST['add_user'] == 'false'` (notice the quotes). I would do a: `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'add_user', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` to get the string boolean back to a normal boolean.

Comment: Ok. I changed that, but this if statement was already functioning as expected (wanted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems in this code:

1. You're assuming that your `register` function will return true on success, but that's not the case.

You need to fix this.

```
public function register($user_id, $fname, $lname, $prefix, $email, $pass, $role, $phone, $dob)
    {
        try
        {
            if($pass !== null)
            {
                $new_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(id, firstname, lastname, prefix, email, password, role, phone, dob, cdate) VALUES(:id, :fname, :lname, :prefix, :email, :pass, :role, :phone, :dob, now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=:fname, lastname=:lname, prefix=:prefix, email=:email, password=:pass, role=:role, phone=:phone, dob=:dob, edate=now()");

                $stmt->bindparam(":pass", $new_password);
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(id, firstname, lastname, prefix, email, role, phone, dob, cdate) VALUES(:id, :fname, :lname, :prefix, :email, :role, :phone, :dob, now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname=:fname, lastname=:lname, prefix=:prefix, email=:email, role=:role, phone=:phone, dob=:dob, edate=now()");

            }

            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $user_id);
            $stmt->bindparam(":fname", $fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lname", $lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":prefix", $prefix);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);

            $stmt->bindparam(":role", $role);
            $stmt->bindparam(":phone", $phone);
            $stmt->bindparam(":dob", $dob);

            return $stmt->execute();

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false; //Probably better to rethrow the exception to let the global error handler handle it but this works too.   
        }    
    }
```

2. You're using `$_POST` values as booleans but they're always going to be coming in as strings. Most IDEs do warn about using $_POST directly and suggest using `filter_input` instead.

Example:

```
 if(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'add_user',FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) == true) { }
```

[Read more on PHP input filters](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Comment: Yes. thank you! I just missed that (must have been staring at it for way too long). And the fact that `$_POST` always evaluates as a string is something I've learned today.

Answer (score 0):

check your User::register method. you expect a boolean return type with your if check. you dont have any return in that method (void). if checking void will always return false (void == null)

return true or false